# iOS 15 Gap between navigation bar and table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode13, ios15

With iOS 15 beta and Xcode 13 beta 2 some custom UITableViewControllers has decided to add padding between the navigation bar and the table view.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Add two UITableViewControllers so the structure looks like this: UINavigationController -> UITableViewController -> UITableViewController.

Add table view delegate method heightForHeaderInSection and return a small value.

In viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods make a API call.

**Actions to solve the problem:**

```objectivec
[self.tableView setSectionHeaderTopPadding:0.0f]; // Not working

[self.tableView setContentInset:-35.0f]; // Works but is not dynamic
```

Tested on Xcode 13 beta 2, iOS 15 beta 2, iPhone 12 Simulator, iPhone Xs

Demo project showing the issue: [Github link](https://github.com/Kjek/Gap-Issue)

The header section should only be 30 pt/px but it's clearly not:

[image]

[Link to original Apple Developer forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683980)

Comment: iOS 15 is beta. Make sure to file a bug with Apple.

Comment: Check my article, tested on your demo project and problem gone. https://medium.com/@GalvinLi/fix-the-table-header-gap-in-ios-15-197debb92608

Answer (score 7):

You can try using [`UITableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/3750914-sectionheadertoppadding) like this -

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to add that I've already tried that and it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: does not work for me iOS 15.2 compiled with Xcode 13.